# Heroku deployment fail

Tags: node.js

I have created an extension connected to MongoDB, now for it to work I need to `npm start server`. Locally it works, now I have to upload the server to a host. I went with Heroku, the problem is the build  loads to a point then fails (times out). I don't understand what changes I have to do.

```json
 /// package.json 
 "name": "face_it",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index-popup.js",
 "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "start": "node server/server.js",
   "build": "webpack -p"
 },
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "mustapha ait boukhliq/Florin 'shadi'",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
   "axios": "^0.24.0",
   "cors": "^2.8.5",
   "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
   "express": "^4.18.1",
   "mongoose": "^6.3.5",
   "react": "^16.14.0",
   "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
   "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
   "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
   "styled-components": "^5.3.3"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
   "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
   "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
   "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
   "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
   "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.2",
   "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
   "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.1.1",
   "html-loader": "^1.3.0",
   "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.4.1",
   "jest": "^27.4.7",
   "webpack": "^4.44.2",
   "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
   "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
 }
}
```

```js
/// server.js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./modules/face_it');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: `${__dirname}/./config.env` });
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json({ limit: '5000mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: "5000mb" }));

app.post('/', async (req, res)=>{
    
    try{
        let exists = [];
        let users = req.body.users;
        if(!users) return res.json({
            status:'ok',
            exists
        });
        for (let index = 0; index < users.length; index++) {
            const user = users[index];
            let checkUser = await User.findOne({ username: user });
            if(checkUser){
                exists.push(checkUser);
            }
        }
        res.json({
            status:'ok',
            exists
        });

    }catch(er){
        console.log(er.message);
    }
});

app.put('/',async (req, res)=>{
    
    try{
        var query = {username: req.query.username},
        update = { badge: req.query.badge },
        options = { upsert: true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true };
    
        // Find the document
        await User.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options);
        res.json({
            status:'ok',
        });

    }catch(er){
        console.log(er.message);
    }
});
app.delete('/',async (req, res)=>{
    try{
        var query = { username: req.query.username };
        console.log(query);
        // Find the document
        await User.findOneAndDelete(query);
        res.json({
            status:'ok',
        });

    }catch(er){
        console.log(er.message);
    }
});

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(connectio => {
    console.log('connection to dataBase successful');
}).catch((er) => {
    console.log(er.message);
    console.log('bad auth/db');
});

app.listen(7452, ()=>{
    console.log('server live!');
});
```

```
/// build progress
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 16.x...
       Downloading and installing node 16.15.1...
       Using default npm version: 8.11.0
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       added 1359 packages, and audited 1360 packages in 26s
       
       99 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       8 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 7 high)
       
       To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
         npm audit fix --force
       
       Run `npm audit` for details.
       
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > face_it@1.0.0 build
       > webpack -p
webpack is watching the files…
       Hash: 867a8cb19e69c5a55d05
       Version: webpack 4.46.0
       Time: 10610ms
       Built at: 06/21/2022 10:21:09 AM
                      Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
       foreground.bundle.js    172 KiB       0  [emitted]  foreground
            icon128x128.png   5.08 KiB          [emitted]  
              icon16x16.png  569 bytes          [emitted]  
              icon48x48.png    1.8 KiB          [emitted]  
                 index.html  208 bytes          [emitted]  
              manifest.json  666 bytes          [emitted]  
            popup.bundle.js    168 KiB       1  [emitted]  popup
                  setter.js   93 bytes          [emitted]  
       Entrypoint popup = popup.bundle.js
       Entrypoint foreground = foreground.bundle.js
       [16] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 552 bytes {0} {1} [built]
       [39] multi regenerator-runtime/runtime.js ./src/index-popup.js 40 bytes {1} [built]
       [40] multi regenerator-runtime/runtime.js ./src/index-foreground.js 40 bytes {0} [built]
       [41] ./src/index-popup.js + 1 modules 26.4 KiB {1} [built]
            | ./src/index-popup.js 195 bytes [built]
            |     + 1 hidden module
       [42] ./src/index-foreground.js + 1 modules 32.4 KiB {0} [built]
            | ./src/index-foreground.js 220 bytes [built]
            |     + 1 hidden module
           + 38 hidden modules
       Child HtmlWebpackCompiler:
            1 asset
           Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_0 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
              1 module
Timed out running buildpack Node.js
Terminated
 !     Push failed
```

and then just fails the push.

Comment: Your `build` process appears to _watch_ the files, which means it _never finishes_ so the deployment can't continue.

Comment: are you putting the environment variables in heroku.... heroku needs to access process.env.DATABASE,  are you doing that correctly?

Comment: I have added the connection string in the config vars , and it's also in my config.env..